# Forcing a push to a page after a pop

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, push, pushviewcontroller, viewwillappear

I have a screen where the user creates a login and presses the save button. At this point I pop back to the previous screen full of saved logins like this ...

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

However, in this scenario only (once they have pressed save), I want to automatically push the user to another screen (effectively logging them in using the login they just made). This is to ensure that if the user goes back a screen, they return to the list of logins and not to the 'create new login' screen.

My question is how can I force this push in this scenario? Can I somehow make the logins page recognise when the user has just come back from successfully making a login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

if(isLoggedIn)
{
//Do something
}
else
{
//Show login
}
}
```

Or if you are using a centralized navigation controller
you can do this in your login view controller

```
- (IBAction)saveButtonPressed
{
[yourAppDelegate.mainNavigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[yourAppDelegate.mainNavigationController pushViewController:nextView animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Hi 7KV7. Thanks for your response. In regards to both of your answers, as I understand them, I would have to pass into my CreateLogin page either a BOOL 'isLoggedIn'(to be set when save is pressed) or the page I wish to pop to 'nextView'. Am I right? If so, is there no way to simply make viewWillAppear know that it has come from CreateLogin after a succesful save?

Comment: You can have a BOOl variable or you can save the status of login to NSUserDefaults too which i guess is suited for one time login or something like that

Comment: This is probably a very noob question (I'm not experienced with pointers), but I'm struggling to pass a BOOL from my SavedLogins page into my CreateLogin class, that will be set in both classes when set in CreateLogin. (or am I totally doing the wrong thing.)

Comment: BOOL is not a pointer. Make sure u add @synthesize and @property to the variable

Comment: In both classes I have synthesize and property like this ... @property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL loginSaved; ... In the init of CreateLogin, the BOOL gets set with the other BOOL like this ... loginSaved=lS; ... However, setting one BOOL doesnt change the original BOOL.

Comment: This works now. My logins page simply needed to hold a reference to the CreateLogin page and access CreateLogin's boolean when it reappeared. However, I needed to the push to the next screen in ViewDidAppear for it to work properly.